# set attribute from value of method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

I am sure I am just doing this wrong, can someone point me in the right direction?

I need to set the value of effective_date to a modified format date

`effective_date` is an attribute of Request

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base

  def format_date=(format_date)
    date_a = format_date.split("/")
    month, day, year = date_a
    effective_date = Date.parse("#{year}-#{month}-#{day}")
  end

  def format_date
    effective_date
  end
end
```

`Request.create(format_date: "04/21/2012")` is not setting the value to effect_date

Edit: I guess this doesn't make sense, so I will try and explain it better:

I need to set the value of effective_date (a column in the database) from format_date (not a column in the database).  I am using format_date method to convert the date from format_date  and store it into effective_date.  If this isn't enough info, let me know.  I am not sure what else to add.

Comment: Is `format_date` a column in the table `requests` ?

Comment: not it is not.  sorry I did not add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `effective_date` is the column name in your database, the change is as simple as

```
def format_date=(format_date)
  date_a = format_date.split("/")
  month, day, year = date_a
  self.effective_date = Date.parse("#{year}-#{month}-#{day}")
end
```

The only change was `effective_date =` to `self.effective_date =`. Without adding `self` there, there's no way for the interpreter to know whether you want to set a local variable called `effective_date` or call the `effective_date=` method. It assumes the local variable.

Comment: that is what I was missing!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If `effective_date` is attribute but not in the table, then I think you need instance variable.

```
class Request < AR::Base
  ...
  def format_date=(f_date)
    ...
    @effective_date = Date.parse("#{year}-#{month}-#{day}")
  end

  def format_date
    @effective_date
  end
end
```

Also, it's not good to use local variable with the name as the name of method (format_date), here's no mistake but it's kinda misleading.

UPDATE: You can see more aboute virtual attributes here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes?view=asciicast

http://railscasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes

Comment: thanks for the tip on the format_date variable I will change that.  I guess I am really making something easy confusing.  If I have to make this as easy as possible:  I want to be able to have format_date be a text_field in a form.  Then I want to convert the date to a usable rails date and store it in the column effective_date in the requests table.  format_date does not exist in the table and effective_date does.  I might be going about this all wrong and there is a simple answer that I am missing.

Comment: I don't see the mistake, what you're doing is called a virtual attributes, see the update.